# php check empty or null in many variables

Tags: php, if-statement

Hello I have a simple script

This is my script, and try this script

```
 <?php 
        $user_id             = $_REQUEST['user_id'];
        $pid                 = $_REQUEST['pid'];
        $nopr                = $_REQUEST['nopr'];
        $tglpr               = $_REQUEST['tglpr'];
        $uraianpr            = $_REQUEST['uraianpr'];
        $jenispr             = $_REQUEST['jenispr'];
        $nilaipr             = $_REQUEST['nilaipr'];
        $costproject         = $_REQUEST['costproject'];
        $remarkpr            = $_REQUEST['remarkpr'];
        $tmpattachid         = $_REQUEST['tmpattachid'];

if ($user_id==NULL)
{
  $error "User Id Not Complete";
}
else if ($pid==NULL)
{
  $error= "PID Not Complete";
}
echo $error;
    ?>
```

I want if $user_id or other variables is **empty/null**

i confused when other variable have empty/null data
i must typing code many **if statement** :(

example : 5 variables ($pid,$nopr,$tglpr,$jenispr,$costproject) is **empty/null**

this show error like this

```
 PID Not Complete
 NoPR Not Complete
 Tgl Pr Not Complete
 Jenis Pr Not Complete
 Cost Project Not Complete
```

Help Me, Thank's.

Comment: Loop through `$_REQUEST`???

Comment: yup, if 3 variables null, then show 3 error
if 5 variables null, then show 5 error

Comment: So what's the problem? You don't know how to make a loop?

Comment: i don't know create looping like this. so can you help me ?

Comment: I'm not going to teach you how to write a `for` loop, no. Open page 1 in your book and go from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the `$_REQUEST` and find the empty or null key.

CODE :

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value) {

    if(trim($value) ==='' || is_null($value))
    {
        echo $key . " is not complete" . "<br/>";
    }

}
```

Comment: you should also tidy up your `foreach` elements at the end of your loop.

Answer (score 2):

I won't give you the full answer, as stated in comments, this is a basic *basic* concept you need to learn, but I will show you the template.

You want to use a `FOREACH` loop to check each value in the array. See http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

And Set it out like this:

```
foreach($_REQUEST as $key=>$row){
    if (is_null($row) || empty($row)){
     $errorText .= "You have no data in your ".$key."<br>";
     }
}
unset($key,$row);
```

Then you can output the `$errorText` value telling people which rows should be fixed. Easy.